# Can't login with blank password on Lion OSX

Tags: macos, passwords, login

Having slight issue with my Lion install. I removed the password from the admin account as it's not desired. However when I'm on the login screen, it wont accept the blank password. It shows the user account and a password box, and when you enter wrong password it gives you the hint.

The only way I've found to get in is by constantly spamming the user icon until it logs in.

Has anybody else experienced this or knows of a fix?

Comment: [It is not usually possible to use a blank password for an admin account.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l1J6e.png), so it appears you're using an unsupported configuration and shouldn't wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Some password prompts in the shell (such as those displayed by sudo by default) shouldn't accept an empty password either.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't want an password on an *admin* account. Are you hoping to get hacked, or are you hoping to shoot yourself in the foot, or are you thinking you'll be able to dodge both of those bullets?

Comment: well all I did was go into Users & Accounts, removed the pass. and it works, when system changes are being made the prompt comes up to login, i can just hit enter. and it accepts the blank password happily. also when inside terminal i can use sudo, when it asks for password i just hit return and it logs in happily also. and the reason i don't want a password is. Im not precious with the data on here, if anybody was to steal it then all they need to do is google "reset password osx" and put a disc in. and they have access anyway. hardly worth it no realistic beneficial scenario i need one for.

Comment: Neither of the two usual options for resetting the login password resets the keychain password though. (It's separate from the login password even though they are usually the same.) I still can't get an empty password to work in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, by re running the setup assistance, and unticking the "require password on login" box that it fixed the issue and didnt ask for a password anymore!

Comment: You could've also just enabled automatic login in the login options section of the Users & Groups preferences.

Answer (score 3):

I clicked on my user icon above the password box and it let me in. Somewhat unexpected functionality if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

On High Sierra, clicking the user's icon no longer works. Try this:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the username and password entry mode.
2. Enter the username (either the account's username or full name).
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter a blank password.
5. You should be logging in now.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this, but there was a workaround to get in so I *could* fix it.

To get in, I had to click the user icon twice. Once in, I went into the user accounts preference pane and clicked **Login Options**. There, I disabled the **Show Password Hints** setting. Now, pressing return at the login prompt works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems you removed the password to be able to use sudo without a password.

If this is your reason you choose the wrong solution: you can easily configure sudo **not** to ask for a password:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

and then add

```
yourusername   ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

see `man sudoers`